# how many five-digit positive integers exist for which the sum of the digits and the product are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, combinations

Determine how many five-digit positive integers exist for which the sum of the digits and the product of the digits have the same value.
By using $(x_1+x_2+...+x_n) \le  n\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2\cdots x_n} $ I have determined the lower limit: 8.
By writing a simple program I can see that there are only 3 variants: 11125, 11133, 11222.
If I prove the upper limit is 10, after which the sum becomes smaller then the product (not counting 111X), I can prove by simply trying all the combinations which sum is between 8 and 10.
Is it possible to do so, or I need a different approach?

Comment: You cannot use this inequality. The correct one is the opposite:
$$
\frac{\sum x_i}{n} \ge \left(\prod x_i\right)^{1/n}.
$$
If $X:=\sum x_i=\prod x_i$ is "large" then there is no contradiction here.

Comment: @Damir: Lucid your method. Congratulations.

Comment: @Piquito Am I wrong?

Comment: @Paolo Leonetti: Not, but Damir's mistake was a simple lapse.

Comment: It was a mistake in the formulation, $\sqrt[5](sum) \le sum/5 $ 
$n^4 \le 5^5$

Comment: @Damir So, how do you get the lower bound?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the initial explanation, but the calculations should be right: 
$\sqrt[5](sum) \le sum/5$; $5^5 \le n^4$; n >= 7.47

Comment: In the statement you had $n=5$. Now what is $n$?

Comment: I just got confused with my initial notes, sorry, n is the sum

Comment: So $n:=\sum_i x_i$ and $\sqrt[5]{n} \le n/5$. Fine, this implies that $n\ge 7.47..$ (I believe the calculation) and, since it is positive integer, then $n\ge 8$. However, your sum is in the range $n \in \{5,6,\ldots,45\}$. Hence, you just eliminated the cases $n \in \{5,6,7\}$. Essentially, everything will be done by the computer program. The question is whether one can do better.

Comment: Yes, my question is, is it possible to prove that for the upper limit, by using the ratios of sum and product, or should I find a different approach?

Comment: Well, with a different approach you do surely better.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help

Comment: I will write you a way below in a few

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ to denote multiplication. That a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics where it has other meanings. Use `\times` ($\times$), `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or ideally simply use juxtaposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it completely without a computer.

Set $S:=\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i$ and $P:=\prod_{i=1}^5 x_i$ be the sum and the product of the digits $x_1,\ldots,x_5 \in \{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ of your number in base $10$. Note that, if $S=P$, then each $x_i$ is nonzero (otherwise the product would be zero and the sum is positive). What you can do is to reason "by hand".

$\bullet$ Suppose $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_5\}\ge 3$. Then $9\cdot 5 \ge S=P \ge 3^5$, which is false.

$\bullet$ Suppose $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_5\}=2$. Let $k$ be the number of those $2$ among the digits $\{x_1,\ldots,x_5\}$. Then
$$
45-7k=2k+9(5-k) \ge S = P \ge 2^k 3^{5-k}.
$$
This is false for every $k \in \{1,\ldots,5\}$.

$\bullet$ By the previous two bullets, you know that
$$
\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_5\}=1.
$$
Let us start again, suppose $x_5=1$ and define $S^\prime:=\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i$ and $P^\prime:=\prod_{i=1}^4 x_i$. The diophantine equation will now be
$$
1+S^\prime=S=P=P^\prime.
$$
Suppose $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_4\}\ge 3$. Then $9\cdot 4+1 \ge 1+S^\prime=P^\prime \ge 3^4$, which is false. Suppose $\min\{x_1,\ldots,x_4\}=2$, wlog $x_4=2$. Then your equation becomes
$$
1+2+x_1+x_2+x_3=2x_1x_2x_3.
$$
However, $2t\ge t+2$ for all $t\ge 2$ and $ab\ge a+b$ for all $a,b\ge 2$, hence
$$
(x_1+2)+(x_2+x_3+1)=1+2+x_1+x_2+x_3=1+S^\prime
$$
and
$$
P^\prime=2x_1x_2x_3 \ge (x_1+2)x_2x_3 \ge (x_1+2)(x_2+x_3) \ge (x_1+2+x_2)+(x_1+2+x_3).
$$

$\bullet$ The above points imply that, if $x_5\le x_4\le x_3\le x_2\le x_1$ and $S=P$ then necessarily
$$
x_4=x_5=1.
$$
Therefore your equation can be simply rewritten as
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+2=S=P=x_1x_2x_3.
$$
(You are left with 27 cases (most of them are trivially false), which can be done by hand. However, let's continue.)

$\bullet$ Note that $(2,2,2,1,1)$ is a solution and $(x_1,2,2,1,1)$ does not work for all $x_1\ge 3$. Now, suppose $x_3=\min\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} \ge 2$ and $x_1=\max\{x_1,x_2,x_3\} \ge 3$. Since $3t\ge t+8$ for all $t\ge 4$ with equality iff $t=4$ and $(x_2,x_3) \neq (2,2)$ so $x_2x_3 \ge x_2+x_3+1$, then
$$
9+x_2+x_3 \ge x_1+x_2+x_3+2=x_1x_2x_3 \ge x_2x_3+8 \ge x_2+x_3+9.
$$
Here, we have equality on the left only if $x_1=9$. However, if $x_1=9$, then the inequality on the right is strict.

$\bullet$ To sum up, if $(x_1,\ldots,x_5)$ is a solution then either it is $(2,2,2,1,1)$ or
$$
x_3=x_4=x_5=1.
$$
However, in such case, the diophantine equation is simply
$$
x_1+x_2+3=S=P=x_1x_2
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x_1=\frac{x_2+3}{x_2-1}=1+\frac{4}{x_2-1}.
$$
So $x_2-1$ is a positive divisor of $4$. This leads to the remaining solutions
$$
(5,2,1,1,1) \text{ and } (3,3,1,1,1).
$$

Comment: Loved your pedagogy! 
And opening with "You can do it completely without a computer" was just a killer. Explanations like this really foster great thinking and logic building skills and assures we are still smarter and master of the Machines.